# Tengo un problema con el incremento en while

Tags: php

Me genera un resultado infinito cuando lo ejecuto

```
  <?php
            
        $i = 1;
        while ($i <= 10) {
            echo $i;
        }
```

Comment: Tu sintaxis esta mal: https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.while.php

Comment: Ampliando la información dada... Tienes que crear una condicion de salida. En algún momento debe salir. Tu salida del while es `$i <10` pero el valor de $i siempre es 1, ya que no esta aumentando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón de que esto suceda es que en esta parte:

```
echo $i;
```

Lo único que haces es que te imprime el valor basado en tu condición de while:

```
while ($i <= 10)
```

**Solución 1 **
Para eliminar el problema tienes que aplicarle un incremento que se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php


$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i++;               /* el valor presentado sería
                               $i antes del incremento */
                    
}
```

**Explicación**

$i++ es lo mismo que si aplicamos i$=$i+1; pero como deberias de empezar a ahorrar lineas de código utilizamos el $i++

**Solución 2**

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10):
    echo $i;
    $i++;
endwhile;
?>
```

**Explicación**

En este ejemplo solo especificamos que el while termino

```
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

No incrementas el valor de $i

```
 <?php
            
        $i = 1;
        while ($i <= 10) {
            echo $i++;
        }
```

Te falta en el echo poner el incremento unitario. Si la $i no cambia, la condición del While siempre va a ser cierta